# Count number of pairs of points with given Manhattan distance

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I have of **P** points with integer coordinates (denoted by **(xi,yi)** ).

0 <= xi <= n ; 0 <= yi <= m
(i=1,2...P)

2 <= n,m <= 100

I am interested to find how many pairs of points are exactly **d** distance apart. It is clear that 1 <= d <= m+n-2 and P<= m* n. I want to calculate number of pairs for each **d**. What is the fastest way to that? (I can find this by looping over d and for each d checking every pair. which is very slow process)

```
e.g.
points : (0,2);(0,3);(2,1)
for d=1 : 1 pair
for d=2 : 0 pairs
for d=3 : 1 pair
for d=4 : 1 pair
for d=5 : 0 pairs
```

Comment: source: https://www.codechef.com/SNCK1A19/problems/AVGMAT

Comment: I have voted to close down this question. Thanks @beaker

Comment: @AndrewScott Questions should not be closed solely because they're part of a programming competition. If the question is a valid algorithm question on its own, it should probably stay. I only point out the source in case potential answerers might want to hold off on replying for, oh, about 11 more hours. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278771/how-to-deal-if-the-user-asks-for-code-in-online-programming-competition

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: Do you need this for a particular d or for all d ?

Comment: I want to calculate this for all d

Answer (score 2):

Below is an algorithm with N×M complexity to get the number of pairs of points for a single distance d. To get the sum for all distances, run this algorithm for every value of d. The overall complexity would then be N×M×(N+M), which should fit the time constraint.

(There are alternative approaches; you could build a grid with the running total of 1's per diagonal, and then read out the number of 1's on each diagonal at distance d from a certain point by subtracting two numbers. This would have a similar theoretical complexity, but may be faster in real terms.)

---

(We'll be using the input given as a binary grid, as in the original question on CodeChef, not as a list of coordinates as you suggest.)

Let's look at the geometry of the Manhattan distance:

```
 6 5 4 3 4 5 6
 5 4 3 2 3 4 5
 4 3 2 1 2 3 4
 3 2 1 X 1 2 3
 4 3 2 1 2 3 4
 5 4 3 2 3 4 5
 6 5 4 3 4 5 6
```

You'll notice that the points at distance d are on diagonal lines, forming a diamond shape around the point, and there are 4×d of them; e.g. for distance d=3:

```
       3
     3 . 3
   3 . . . 3
 3 . . X . . 3
   3 . . . 3
     3 . 3
       3
```

We don't want to count every pair twice, so we'll only look at two of the four sides of the diamond:

```
       A
     . . A
   . . . . A
 . . . X . . B
   . . . . B
     . . B
       .
```

If the center point X has value 1, then the sum of values of the points A and B can be added to the total of pairs that are at distance d.

We can iterate over the grid to find the total in two diagonal motions; first, let's check the point A's on the top-right side of the diamond around every point. We look at  diagonals that are at distance d from each other, e.g. for a 7×6 grid with distance 3:

```
 . . . . . . .     . . . . . . .     A . . . . . .     . A . . . . .
 . . . . . . .     A . . . . . .     . A . . . . .     . . A . . . .
 A . . . . . .     . A . . . . .     . . A . . . .     X . . A . . .
 . A . . . . .     . . A . . . .     X . . A . . .     . X . . A . .
 . . A . . . .     X . . A . . .     . X . . A . .     . . X . . A .
 X . . A . . .     . X . . A . .     . . X . . A .     . . . X . . A     etc...
```

For each of these, we iterate over the X-diagonal, and if the value of a point X is 1, we add the sum of the values of the d points A that are above it to the total, e.g.:

```
 A . . . . . .     . . . . . . .     . . . . . . .
 . A . . . . .     . A . . . . .     . . . . . . .
 . . A . . . .     . . A . . . .     . . A . . . .
 X . . . . . .     . . . A . . .     . . . A . . .
 . . . . . . .     . X . . . . .     . . . . A . .
 . . . . . . .     . . . . . . .     . . X . . . .
```

As you can see, the sum of the values of the d point A's can be calculated using a sliding window, so we have to iterate over the values on every diagonal only once.

We then do the same for the diagonals in the other direction:

```
 X . . B . . .     . X . . B . .     . . X . . B .     . . . X . . B
 . . B . . . .     X . . B . . .     . X . . B . .     . . X . . B .
 . B . . . . .     . . B . . . .     X . . B . . .     . X . . B . .
 B . . . . . .     . B . . . . .     . . B . . . .     X . . B . . .
 . . . . . . .     B . . . . . .     . B . . . . .     . . B . . . .
 . . . . . . .     . . . . . . .     B . . . . . .     . B . . . . .     etc...
```

We are iterating over every diagonal (in both directions) once, so ultimately we've iterated over every point twice, and the complexity of the algorithm is linear to M×N.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just loop over all the pairs of points and compute the distance, and have a map with key being the distance and value being the frequency?

```
for point P1 in P
   for point P2 in P, P2 > P1
      d <- distance(P1,P2) 
      if (mapDistance.get(d) exists)
         increment mapDistance.get(d)
      else 
         mapDistance.put(d,1)
```

Overall complexity is O(P*P)

Comment: O(P*P) = O(n^4). I need a solution faster than this.

Comment: Why would O(P*P) be equal to O(n^4)? It does not make sense IMO. Moreover, you cannot go faster than checking all the pairs of points at least once

Comment: P <= m*n, I agree, but P is not equal to m*n. If you have all the existing points (i.e. any point (x,y) with 0<=x<=n and 0<=y<=m exist once in P), that may be done in constant time by preprocessing. If it is not the case, I do believe that you cannot do better that what I'm proposing.